# String obfuscation makes my jar unrunnable

Tags: java, string, obfuscation

I have a Java project that needs to be obfuscated because of some crucial components. I only need a string obfuscator, the rest isn't really important.

The problem is that when I try many obfuscators, such as Jshrink, JODE, JavaGuard, etc, my jar refuses to launch. Apparently I have some `NoSuchMethodErrors`, and the library Gson by Google that I use also has issues.

My project has a launcher that launches my jar and when I obfuscate my jar, the launcher throws errors.

Are there some settings that I'm missing or do I need another obfuscator? Is there another way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: what obfuscator are you using and what is the current setting for it? If you get a `NoSuchMethodErrors` then you are changing method names, too

Comment: @k3b I'm currently using Jshrink with these settings : http://puu.sh/9QGht/3244a575c2.png
But even if I only set the String obfuscation it doesn't work

Comment: does it work if you remove the obfuscator?

Comment: I'm curious:  How can you obfuscate strings in a program and still have it run?

Comment: @Hot Licks It's pretty simple, the obfuscator integrates some methods to process strings in your code, so that you can't read it clearly even after decompiling your jar. But your jar will work the same. Do some research.

Comment: I believe that you can (within limits) obfuscate class and method names, but if you obfuscate ordinary strings then they will be rendered unusable as meaningful strings.  You can, perhaps, *encrypt* the strings and then use a decrypt mechanism at runtime, but that's an entirely different thing, and apt to be very fragile if "automated" (and not very secure besides).